# How to write into a file at a particular Match

Tags: python

I have one file at the location `"C:\Temp"` the file name is `arun.txt`. The content of the file is like following

```
test=
pqr=
lmn=
```

I want to find the line with 'pqr=' and modfiy this as 'pwr=xyz'

I am not much expert in python.

But following code I have written but its neither doing anything nor returning any error.

```
f = open('C:\Temp\arun.txt', 'r+')
        for line in f.readline():
                if line == "pqr=":
                        f.write('pqr=xyz')
```

Can anyone please suggest me if I am doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open("input.txt") as input, open("output.txt", "w") as output:
    for line in input:
        if line.startswith("pqr="):
            output.write("pqr=xyz\n")
        else:
            output.write(line)
```

Comment: You can combine the two with statements using `,` `with open("input.txt") as input, open("output.txt", "w") as output`

Answer (score 1):

[`fileinput.input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.input) with argument `inplace=True` has your `print` statements redirected to a temporary file which is renamed to your original file to allow inplace editing.

```
for line in fileinput.input('Temp', inplace=True):
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    if line == 'pqr=':
        print line + 'xyz'
    else:
        print line
```

The temporary file is by default, the original file name `+ '.bak'`. This makes the program process safe, as opposed to just using `out.txt` as a file name since you may decide to run this program on another file, which may overwrite `out.txt` as you are writing to it. Another safe approach would be to rename a `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile`